# How to Implement nodemailer module in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, webstorm

I am new to `node.js`. Right now i am on a already created project in `angularjs`. I am using `webstorm` as IDE.

I want to integrate `nodemailer module`. For this i added this module in `node_modules` by copy pasting it.

Now there are some already built in examples in this module. I want to run them, for e.g. i have a `example_sendmail.js` file for sending emails.

How to run this?

Comment: You do realise `node.js` is a server side application, and `angularjs` is a clientside framework which runs in a browser, right?

Comment: @user1066946 yes...i realise it..but right now i am completely confused .. :)

Comment: you can use angular as a client side and node.js - for server side. However I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about. Do you need to know how to run a node.js application (like example_sendmail.js) from within WebStorm? You need using Node.js run configuration for that (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html)